# How to display YouTube view count on a website

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, youtube-api

I want to display view count of a youtube video in a website. The below code is written for it. But it does not print the view count, only shows the youtube video.

Here is my code,

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>How to put PHP in HTML - Simple Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function videoViews() {
            var rex = /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{11}/,
            videoUrl = $('input').val() === '' ? alert('Enter a valid Url'):$('input').val(),
            videoId = videoUrl.match(rex),
            jsonUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + videoId + '?v=2&alt=json',
            embedUrl = '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId,
            embedCode = '<iframe width="350" height="197" src="' + embedUrl + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    
            //Get Views from JSON
            $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function (videoData) {
                var videoJson = JSON.stringify(videoData),
                vidJson = JSON.parse(videoJson),
                views = vidJson.entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
                $('.views').text(views);
            });
    
            //Embed Video
            $('.videoembed').html(embedCode);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="url" placeholder="Enter Youtube video URL"> 
    <a href="#" onClick="videoViews()">GO</a>
    
    <div class="videoembed"></div>
    <div class="views"></div>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $video_ID = substr($_GET['url'], -11);
        $JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={$video_ID}&key=AIzaSyAGquK-QPs8yaddEqhL1AEmYbrJKT6xs04");
        $JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
        $views = $JSON_Data->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;
        echo "<script>$('.views').text($views);</script>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>`
```

I want to display Number of Views of a given video in my website.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code, you are using the YouTube Data API to get the view count for a YouTube video and update the `.views` element with that count. However, in your PHP code, you are trying to do the same thing using a different API endpoint.

To fix the issue and display the view count using the YouTube Data API, you can remove the PHP code and update your JavaScript code as follows:

1. Replace the existing `jsonUrl` variable with the following:

```
var jsonUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' + videoId + '&part=statistics&key=YOUR_API_KEY';
```

Replace YOUR_API_KEY with your own YouTube Data API key.

2. Update the `$.getJSON` function to handle the API response and update the view count on the page. Replace the existing `$.getJSON` function with the following:

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function (data) {
    var views = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
    $('.views').text(views);
});
```

This code gets the view count from the JSON response and updates the `.views` element with that count.

With these changes, your code should now display the view count for the specified YouTube video. Note that you will need to have a valid YouTube Data API key and include it in your API request to retrieve the view count.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more abstract approach for reusability and using plain javascript functions.

We declare a function for the API call which returns a promise. Then we declare a function that returns only the viewCount property from the API response.

```
   function getVideoResponse(video_id) {
        const API_KEY = 'XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX'
        const endpoint = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=${video_id}&key=${API_KEY}&part=snippet,statistics`
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(endpoint)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    /**
                     * We return the first item of the array
                     * If we insert the parameter statistics at the youtube API endpoint
                     * then an object with the below structure is returned from the API call
                     * 
                     * commentCount: string
                     * favoriteCount: string
                     * likeCount: string
                     * viewCount: string
                     */
                    resolve(data.items[0]);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }
    
    async function getYouTubeViewCount(video_id) {
        // We destructure the statistics object and then access viewCount property as described ton api call method above 
        const {statistics} = await getVideoResponse(video_id);
        return statistics.viewCount;
    }
    
    // Call the function to get the views count
    getYouTubeViewCount('VIDEO_ID-XXX-XXX').then((viewsCount) => {
        // do something with the views count here
    })
```